# Blender bone animation with extruded vertex not moving as expected

Tags: animation, blender

I'm really new to blender. I've managed to make a model body and bone structure. 
I've two problems:

1. But when I try to rotate the arm bone, my entire body moves. Why is this happening? I was following a guide and did `ctrl+P` and `armature deform -> with automatic weights` to link the bones to the mesh. What am I doing wrong here?
2. There appears to be some extruded vertex left in the joins of knee and shoulder. How do I fix that?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just assigning parent is not enough. You need to weight paint your mesh, to assign that how much the mesh 'sticks' with the bones. See some rigging/weight painting tutorials.

As for the extruded vertex, I don't understand what you mean. Please send a screenshot of the problem area (in edit mode), and I'll try to help you.

Comment: I ended up redoing the whole model so don't have it atm.. but thanks will read upon it